# Android Tabs with transparent blurred background

Tags: android-layout, android-tabhost, android-tabs, android-tabstrip

I want to show transparent blurred tabs, so that listactivity screen behind it shows blurred images [image]

And tabs without divider.

Comment: Those don't look necessarily as tabs, they may be implemented with normal layouts. Where do you have problems?

Comment: i want to use this view in my whole application, how would i manage for  25 activities.

Comment: The tabs are not blurred, they are only transparent black

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution by removing item selector background from deselect event and the image you want to set in background of tab group just use that image by using set background resource.

In selector make change

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/selected_tab" android:state_selected="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

in tab host make following change

```
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:background="#000000" >
   <RelativeLayout
       android:id="@+id/linearLayoutTab"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:orientation="vertical" >
       <FrameLayout
           android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
       <TabWidget
           android:id="@android:id/tabs"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
           android:layout_marginBottom="-10dp"
           android:tabStripEnabled="true"
           android:background="@drawable/unselected_tab"/>
   </RelativeLayout>
</TabHost>
```